# JavaScript: Are Property Functions Hoisted?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand why the following code works:

```
function checkReading () {
  if (checkReading.read) {
    return; 
  }
  checkReading.read = this.scrollHeight - this.scrollTop === this.clientHeight;
  document.registration.accept.disabled = document.getElementById("nextstep").disabled = !checkReading.read;
  checkReading.noticeBox.innerHTML = checkReading.read ? "Thank you." : "Please, scroll and read the following text.";
}
```

> Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

The part I am struggling with is how `if(checkReading.read)` can be called before the `checkReading.read` property is declared on the `checkReading` function object.

Is the reason this works that function declarations, even when done directly as a property (like above), are hoisted to the top of its scope?

So after JS engine has completed its first tick of the event loop, `checkReading.read` is in fact hoisted (moved) to the top of the `checkReading` function?

PS: I know that normal function declarations are hoisted `function foo() {..}` to the top of their scope, but was not sure if that applies to properties like the above as well.

Comment: Assignments (anything with a `=`) are never hoisted. You also look to be trying to assign properties to the function itself, which isn't the way things should be done - probably better to assign to an object instead. `checkReading.read` can indeed be checked before the property is assigned, it'll just return `undefined`, which is falsey.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The code is an official example from MDN ;) See the source link. I actually thought about the falsy concept, but then the below code would never be reached. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's still a very bad idea

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Functions are objects. Nothing wrong with assigning properties to functions.

Comment: all this is doing is checking to see if the property exists. if the property doesn't exist, it will return `undefined` which will be coerced to `false` for the `if` check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The part I am struggling with is how `if(checkReading.read)` can be called before the `checkReading.read` property is declared on the `checkReading` function object.

This has nothing to with functions or hoisting. You can access non-existing properties on any object:

```js
var foo = {};
console.log(foo.bar);
```

If the property doesn't exist, its return value is `undefined`, which coerces to `false`.

> I actually thought about the falsy concept, but then the below code would never be reached. Or am I missing something?

If the condition is `false`, the body of the `if` statement is **not** executed, i.e. the `return;` is not executed, and therefore the rest of the function is executed.

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't with hoisting, but rather with what happens when you access an uninitialized value in these different cases.

If you never declare the variable before it is read, you get a ReferenceError:

```
if (a) { foo(); }  // ReferenceError thrown
let a;
```

...unless it's a `var` or `function` in which case hoisting applies:

```
function home() {
    if (a || b()) { foo(); }
    var a;
    function b() {}
}
```

However, object property accesses are different. Object property access will never, ever throw a ReferenceError. Object properties also cannot be declared, really-- they are just created/modified/used as part of the object.

```
if (!a.foo) { a.foo = new Foo(); }
// Use a.foo
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, PA. The last paragraph was particularly helpful. I had not thought about that before.